# oozie coordinator jobs not starting at the given start time

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am using oozie coordinator for scheduling my hadoop jobs.
I give the start time as 12:26, but it start after 8-9 hours and it complete all the remaining jobs according to frequency I given in my job property file.

Why this halt of 8 hours, still it is completing the remaining jobs using the startTime i given in the job.properties?

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020
jobTracker=localhost:8021
queueName=default

oozie.libpath=${nameNode}/user/oozie/share/lib
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.rerun.failnodes=true


appPath=${nameNode}/user/user1/mr
oozie.wf.application.path=${appPath}



frequency=60
jobStart=2014-12-31T12:26Z
jobEnd=2015-12-16T23:00Z
timezone=GMT+0530

inputDir=${nameNode}/user/user1/input
outputDir=${nameNode}/user/user1/output

oozie.coord.application.path=${appPath}/coordinator.xml
```

coordinator.xml

```
<coordinator-app name="LogCoordinator" frequency="${frequency}" start="${jobStart}" end="${jobEnd}" timezone="${timezone}" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1">
<action>
<workflow>
<app-path>${appPath}</app-path>
</workflow>
</action>          
</coordinator-app>
```

Is there any timeZone Issue?

Comment: welcome to SO ! to get the most correct answer and to help other help you - please add all the relevant details - e.g the coordinator.xml

Comment: Thanks, I added coordinator.xml which I am using in my oozie workflow.

Comment: hi sumet ji!! did you cross checked the GMT time to our IST time!!

Comment: @srs_karthik thanks, that is the only problem, I was setting GMT and it was starting after 6 hours. Thanks for your Succession.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you cross checked the GMT time to our IST time!! Make sure that the IST time to your jobstart variable.

Comment: I checked it by change time from 12:26 to 06:54, then it starts on 12:26 IST. But when i use GMT+05:30 it shows only GMT in oozie job -info and job is starting after 5:30 hours.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to configure "**oozie.processing.timezone**" in the oozie-site.xml ,which has the default value as UTC. Change it to your desired timezone ( IST here ) by specifying (GMT+0530) as its value and restart oozie. Then you have to configure the coordinator.xml with timezone="IST" ( Or GMT+0530). And provide the startTime/endTime in coordinator.properties with the **actual IST** time. UTC timezone has the timeStamp format as (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z') The format for specifying the time will now be changed to **(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm+0530)** i.e if you want your job to run at 05:30(IST) then the value for startTime in properties file will be **( 2018-10-07T05:30+0530 )**. This has worked for me. Hope this helps.